# How can i disable a column without disabling the action buttons?

Tags: php, laravel

By clicking the row 1. with Institute Name, the Lab of this Institute appears on the right size. So everywhere I am clicking the system appears the Labs on the right. So if I click the edit or delete button, the Labs tab continues to pop up, and after a few seconds, the Institute's edit tab opens. Any ideas?

[image]

```
@section('javascript')
<script>
    var laboratories = '{{htmlspecialchars(json_encode($laboratories), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')}}';
    laboratories = laboratories.replace( /&quot;/g, '"' );
    laboratories = JSON.parse(laboratories);
    // console.log(laboratories);
    function getLaboratories(id)
    {
        $("table#laboratories").empty();
        var table = "<tr>" +
            "<th>ID</th>" +
            "<th>{{ __('Laboratory\'s Name') }}</th>" +
            "<th>{{ __('Laboratory\'s Acronym') }}</th>" +
            "<th>{{ __('Actions') }} </th>" +
            "</tr>";
        for(var i=0; i<laboratories[id].length; i++)
        {
            table += '<tr><td>'+id+'.'+(i + 1)+'</td><td>'+laboratories[id][i].name+'</td><td>'+laboratories[id][i].acronym+'</td>';
            table += '<td><a alt="{{ __('Delete Laboratory')}}" title="{{ __('Edit Laboratory')}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="laboratories/'+laboratories[id][i].id+'/edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>' +
                '<form action="laboratories/delete/'+laboratories[id][i].id+'/" method="post" class="form-delete2">{{csrf_field()}}{{method_field('DELETE')}}'+
                '<button alt="{{ __('Delete Laboratory')}}" title="{{ __('Delete Laboratory')}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-default delete" id="delete_modal2" name="delete_modal2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></form></td></tr>';
        }
        $("table#laboratories").append(table);

        // EXTRA
        var href = $("#create_lab").attr('href');
        // console.log(href);
        let positiion = href.search("institute_id");
        href = href.substring(0,positiion)+"institute_id="+id;
        // console.log(href);
        $("#create_lab").attr('href', href)
        $("#create_lab").attr('disabled', false);
    }
</script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <a href="{{route('institutes.create')}}" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> {{ __('Create New Institute') }}</a>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" data-toggle="dataTable" data-form="deleteForm">
                           <tr>
                               <th>ID</th>
                               <th>{{ __('Institute\'s Name') }}</th>
                               <th>{{ __('Institute\'s Acronym') }}</th>
                               <th>{{ __('Actions') }}</th>
                           </tr>
                            @if(count($institutes) > 0)
                                @foreach($institutes as $institute)
                                    <tr onclick="getLaboratories({{$institute->id}});">
                                        <td>{{$institute->id}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$institute->name}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$institute->acronym}}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a alt="{{ __('Edit Institute')}}"title=" {{ __('Edit Institute')}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="{{route('institutes.edit', $institute->id)}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                                            <form action="{{route('institutes.destroy', $institute->id)}}" method="post" class="form-delete">
                                                {{csrf_field()}}
                                                {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                                                <button alt="{{ __('Delete Institute')}}" title="{{ __('Delete Institute')}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-default delete" id="delete_modal" name="delete_modal">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                                                </button>
                                            </form>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            @else
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ __('There are no institutes available.') }}</td>
                                </tr>
                            @endif
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: I think this is a js issue, a click event bubbling or so. Do you have some code for us?

Comment: It's too long. Is there any other way to send this?

Comment: Post the important parts of your code, for example, just the form and the back-end that handles it, not the entire class

Comment: Check my code below

Comment: I have placed your code from answers into your question. It should be edited to only show important parts related to your question though. I will leave that up to you. Good luck!

Comment: To me it looks like you are loading multiple labs in a foreach which is causing nested foreach labs in a single lab in your getLabratories function. You need to change function to get  a single lab by ID

Comment: Also, you are emptying a table with an id that doesnt exist. Hence my last comment

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is a javascript issue rather than a php/laravel problem, anyways: on the click handlers for the buttons you call 'stopPropagation' to stop the click event on the buttons bubbling up to fire the click event on the row. What happens is that a click on the button is ALSO a click on the row, so it reacts to both.

See this example html:

```
<table>
<tr><td>the row<td> <span ><input type="button" value="I am a button"/>           </span></td></td></tr>
</table>

<div id="messages">

</div>
```

and this javascript:

```
$('tr').on('click', function(){
    $('#messages').append('<div>You clicked the row</div>')
})

$('span').on('click', function(e){

$('#messages').append('<div>You click the button</div>')
})
```

As you can see. It fires the event for both the button and the row when you click the button.

if you to this instead:

```
$('tr').on('click', function(){
    $('#messages').append('<div>You clicked the row</div>')
})

$('span').on('click', function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
$('#messages').append('<div>You click the button</div>')
})
```

(notice the 'e.stopProgration();') it will only fire the event for the button.

Comment: I did what you mentioned but disabled and the row also. I want only the column with Actions, Edit and Delete and not all the row.